# Permanent deletion

Tags: support

I need to permanently delete my posts and I am seeing a limit of 10 deleted posts per day, 10 flagged posts per day, and every time I edit a post my changes are rolled back by a moderator. I have emailed the Legal team but am hoping to get some help quickly. Thank you.

Comment: If you've already emailed the Legal team, what further action do you expect to be taken? Also, note that your content won't be removed just because you ask for it. Posting on Stack Exchange gives them the right to host your content as long as they see fit. They are also required to attribute you, but you can ask them to stop doing that if you want.

Comment: Why do you need to delete your posts?

Comment: I posted code snippets that are copyright of my employer. I'm at risk of losing my job.

Comment: @fumeng As mentioned in the linked questions, you can issue Stack Overflow with DMCA notices, explaining the situation and asking them to remove the copyrighted code. They are legally obliged to comply.

Answer (score 36):

So basically...you're deleting the *code* from your questions.  I don't have a lot of time to look too deeply but the pattern is obvious from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61594590/revisions) and [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66147093/revisions).

**Unless** your job comes through with a legal and proper DMCA request, the likelihood of your content being eligible for wholescale removal is slim.  You've published this content and we assumed that you were able to publish it, so the site is within the confines of CC-by-SA to keep it hosted here, and the best you can do is disassociate yourself from it.

What action you're taking now comes across as *vandalism* to any sane outside observer.  You're taking content that existed and just destroying it, which is not cool.

So, you're going to have to hope that some legal entity at the place you work can provide Stack Exchange with a DMCA to get that taken down; otherwise, the best that can happen is disassociation.

Lesson for next time: be sure that it's completely OK to post code from your workplace.