# How many downvotes can a post get for it to be automatically closed or deleted?

Tags: support, downvotes, vote-to-close, vote-to-delete

I've seen a lot of posts with at least -20 downvotes, but they don't get deleted or closed. For example, [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405451/permanent-deletion). Would it not have been a duplicate, it most likely wouldn't have been closed or deleted. Is there a threshold after which a post gets automatically deleted or closed?

Comment: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: [What is a “closed” or “duplicate” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10582)

Comment: @JeanneDark - Just curious, how do you find duplicates or related questions so easily?

Comment: I have already read them.

Comment: You can easily sort by score, and go to the last page. Doing so reveals [an open question with a score below -500](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391250/7296893) on MSO, while on MSE, [we've already passed -1500](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340906/369403), but that question has been locked, and the lowest open and unlocked one is also in the negative 500 range.

Comment: Your example question will never be deleted since it has an answer that received 33 upvotes.  It's basically a sign post at this point to direct users to the duplicates.

Comment: Please don't delete this question, system.  I earned those 35 support tag points. :(

Answer (score 13):

Downvotes do not cause a question to be closed or deleted.

There are different kinds of votes, that require different reputation levels:

- Downvotes (the ones you mention) require [125 reputation points](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down).
- Close Votes [require 3000 reputation points](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions).
- Delete votes [require 10000 reputation points](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

While a negative score and/or being closed *can* [lead to a question to be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions), these are in the end independent processes.

Questions can be automatically deleted if they fulfil the criteria described in the article above, but they cannot be automatically closed. That requires users casting close-votes.